# Align a subset of columns of a matplotlib table to right/left

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I tried the exact same code from one of the answers  on Stackoverflow to justify/align text of few columns but did not get the desired output as shown here :  [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210749/matplotlib-table-assign-different-text-alignments-to-different-columns)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = [['x','x'] for x in range(10)]
bbox = [0,0,1,1]

tb = plt.table(cellText = data, cellLoc='right', bbox = bbox)
plt.axis('off') # get rid of chart axis to only show table

def set_align_for_column(table, col, align="left"):
    cells = [key for key in table._cells if key[1] == col]
    for cell in cells:
        table._cells[cell]._loc = align

set_align_for_column(tb, col=0, align="right")
set_align_for_column(tb, col=1, align="left")

plt.show()
```

I want to justify few columns of a matplotlib table to the right and few to the left. How do I achieve this ?

I am using the latest version of matplotlib package and python 3.8

I even tried using `df.style.set_properties` as a workaround before creating the matplotlib table. It doesn't seem to work!

Output Shown in the Image

[image: 2]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for code. Provide code that can be copied and pasted.

Comment: I didn't because I already linked the source page m Pls read my description fully.

Comment: I have given the snapshot for output purposes

Comment: Most people are not going to click your link...